# My website font looks different on Android and in in iOS

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am using a media query max width 480px for mobile device, The font size I use is 15px it looks fine in IOS, but when I see in Android it looks little bit bigger in size may be 17px. How to make font size similar that looks good in both interface.

Any CSS solution or JavaScript?

Comment: What is the browser you’re using on Android?

Comment: Try to use CSS to specify the font family and font-size in px.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am using chrome on i phone as well in android also

Comment: The two systems may use slightly different font variations and their font rendering strategy differs anyway. Fonts are basically never pixel perfect identical across browsers.

Answer (score -1):

just use rem for font-sizes to avoid any difference's between platforms and screen-sizes.

> REMs are a way of setting font-sizes based on the font-size of the root HTML element. They also allow you to quickly scale an entire project by changing the root font-size